# How to display only those Rails records where a specific field is not empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I'm overlooking something very simple here, but would really appreciate some help to work out what it is.

In the project show view, I'm displaying associated (has_many) tasks in a partial. I only want to display those records where a particular field is not empty. My view code looks like this.

```
<% for task in @tasks %>
    <% unless task.user.notes.empty? %>
    <tr>
         <td><%= task.user.name %></td>
         <td><%= task.user.notes %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is returning `undefined method 'notes' for nil:NilClass`. This is strange as :notes is definitely in the User model.

The Project controller handling this is contains:

```
def show
    @tasks = @project.tasks.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

My models look as follows

```
Project
  has_many :tasks
end

Task
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end

User
  has_many :tasks
end
```

What have I missed here? Am I using `empty?` correctly? Or should I be handling this in the controller? I currently have three partials on the Project show, all using the same Task query. Performance and/or best practice -wise, does it make more sense to have all three partials sourcing data from the same controller query, or to have a sperate query just for this case?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: The problem is that the ```user``` association is nil when you call ```task.user```. Check to make sure that every ```Task``` in the database has a ```user_id```

Comment: Thanks carlosramirezii, this was indeed the issue. A mistake in some of my test data. Building on this, is my approach here the best way to go? I know people generally say don't put logic in the view. But with three partials using the same query, what are the pros and cons of running a separate query versus doing this in the view. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Andy- I don't think your view logic was too unreasonable, but I added a new answer below which explains how to improve your best practices. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that your `User` model was undefined when you called `task.user.notes`.

You can solve this problem as well as improve your overall design by making use of the `#delegate` macro provided by `ActiveSupport` in `Rails`. For example, inside of the `Task` model, try adding

`delegate :notes, :to => :user, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true`

This adds a `task.user_notes` method to the `Task` model which will allow you to fetch the `User`'s `notes` straight from the `Task` itself. Additionally, because we specified the `allow_nil` option, if there is no `User` associated with the `Task`, the result of the method will be `nil` instead of an exception.

You can also add this for the `name` attribute of the `User` allowing you to call `task.user_name` from within the view.

Resources:

- `delegate` -  http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/Module/delegate
- "Law of Demeter" - http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/

Answer (score 2):

**In the controller**

```
def show
   @tasks = @project.tasks.paginate(
     :page => params[:page],
     :conditions=>["notes is not ? and notes !=?",nil,'']
   )
end
```

**OR, not in the controller**

Write a helper method to abstract this.

**Add a new helper method**

```
def filter_tasks(tasks)
  tasks.find(
    :all,
    :conditions=>["notes is not ? and notes !=?",nil,'']
  )
end
```

**And use helper in view**

```
<% for task in filter_tasks(@tasks) %>
  <% unless task.user.notes.empty? %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= task.user.name %></td>
      <td><%= task.user.notes %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer Teddy. What I'd really like to know is your opinions on achieving this in the view versus he controller. I know people normal say don't implement logic in the view, but with three partials using the same query, this seems like a special case. What are the performance implications of achieving this in the view, versus running a separate query just for this?

Comment: Thanks Teddy, this looks like it would work, but I've decided to implement carlosramireziii solution above.